# Store variable in Session

Tags: php, mysql, session

I want to store the user_level from my mysql db of the user who submits the form in the `$_SESSION`
My code currently is this:

```
    <form id='login' action='<?php echo $fgmembersite->GetSelfScript(); ?>' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
    <fieldset >
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
    {
 session_start();
    if($fgmembersite->Login())
       {

        $mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'name', 'psw', 'db');
                if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT user_level FROM users WHERE username='$username'")) {

                 $_SESSION['user_level'] = $result;     
            } 
            $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("loginhome.php");

       }       

    } 
    ?>

    <legend>Login</legend>

    <input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>

    <div class='short_explanation'>* benötigte Felder</div>

    <div><span class='error'><?php echo $fgmembersite->GetErrorMessage(); ?></span></div>
    <div class='container'>
        <label for='username' >Benutzername*:</label><br/>
        <input type='text' name='username' id='username' value='<?php echo $fgmembersite->SafeDisplay('username') ?>' maxlength="50" /><br/>
        <span id='login_username_errorloc' class='error'></span>
    </div>
```

Now I checked it on the site, where you got redirected with `print_r($_SESSION);` and I get this result:

```
[user_level] => mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => [field_count] => [lengths] => [num_rows] => [type] => )
```

Can anyone explain to me what happens there? Or what went wrong?

Comment: You need to use mysql_fetch_assoc to extract the data from object which is $result

Comment: `$mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'name', 'psw', 'db');
 $data = array();
 if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT user_level FROM users WHERE username='$username'")) {
  while($res = $result->fetchAll(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
  $data[] = $res;

  }
                      
    }
    $_SESSION['user_level'] = $data;`

Comment: Sadly, with this my loginform disappears

Answer (score 1):

This probably will not fix your issue but a session should always be started at the utmost top of your script.

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}

// ... Other code ...
```

There is also an issue with your query. You should use it like:

```
$conn = new mysqli('host', 'username', 'password', 'database');
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $editID);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

print_r($row);
```

Comment: Hm, my loginform disappears. But I can't print the `$row` as the loginform is not yet submitted? because there is no value for `'$username'`.

Comment: @pr0cz  when you have this `$fgmembersite->Login()` then why not in that function only save the data to session, again one more query and result fetching? that is unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1) Start `session` at top of page

2) you should fetch data in `associative array` and then assign value in `session` `variable`

```
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $_SESSION['user_level'] =  $row['user_level'];
    }
```

Comment: instead of  `$_SESSION['user_level'] = $result;` ?

Comment: Okay, now it doesn't show the `user_level` in the `print_r` tag anymore.

Comment: try to print $row and check what it contains

Comment: it doesn't get printed on the redirected page